# How to use python variable as a part of <a href = in html?

Tags: python, html

This time I need to know how can I use python variable to create a href link in html which is part of a python script.

For instance,

```
LinkX = "file://///server/folderX
```

where folderX changes all the time and then to use this LinkX as a part of

```
<a href = "folderX">LinkX</a>.
```

Something like this.
Thank you.

Comment: Ok. Solved. Thanks to:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137520/how-to-pass-python-variable-to-html-variable?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137520/how-to-pass-python-variable-to-html-variable?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you are generating the html as text, you can use string formatting:

```
link = '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(destination, description)
```

Comment: It should be a link which is sent via email with python.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
>>> linkUrl = 'file://///server/folderX'
>>> linkText = '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(linkUrl, 'Folder X')
>>> linkText
'<a href="file://///server/folderX">Folder X</a>'
```