# Issue with HTTP GET Parameters in Python CGI

Tags: python, html

I am learning web development in Python. When I open the HTML I get the Ferrari Fiat Ford, which is what I am expecting but then I click on Ferrari and it opens up the new page as make, model, which is not what I want. I want Ferrari Dino.

Could you help me understand what is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Python Response</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
       <a href="get.py?make=Ferrarri&model=Dino">Ferrari</a>
       <a href = 'get.py?make = Fiat & model = Topolino'>Fiat</a>
       <a href = 'get.py?make = Ford & model = Mustang'>Ford</a>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Python

```
import cgi

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

make = data.getvalue('make')
model = data.getvalue('model')

print ( 'Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n' )
print ( '''<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang = "en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Python Response</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>, make, model,</h1>
            <a href = "get.html">Back</a>
        </body>
        </html>''' )
```

Comment: I suggest a better question title, one that describes the problem in general, for example "Issue with HTTP GET Parameters in Python CGI"

Comment: If you wanna learn about how should a Python web application look like, ignore everything you are trying to do and follow this guide blindly: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable cannot be a string.

```
import cgi

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

make = data.getvalue('make')
model = data.getvalue('model')

print ( 'Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n' )
print ( '''<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang = "en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Python Response</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>, ''' + make + ', ' + model + ''',</h1>
            <a href = "get.html">Back</a>
        </body>
        </html>''' )
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing this out, the HTML is responding as anticipated.

My recommendation goes along lines of this question here: [How to pass python variable to html variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137520/how-to-pass-python-variable-to-html-variable)

In summary, you could do this in a better way by writing a function and returning the html. Also, once you've written the python function, rather than have the:

```
<h1>, make, model,</h1>
```

You could use a substitution in your python function like so:

```
"<h1>, %s, %s,</h1>" % (make, model)
```

Which would be located in the same python file as the two of these variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your template outputs this:

```
<h1>, make, model,</h1>
```

And that's all it ever will output.  You can instead change it a little and then use the format method to insert values into it.

```
html = '''<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Python Response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>, {make}, {model},</h1>
        <a href = "get.html">Back</a>
    </body>
    </html>'''

print html.format(make=make, model=model)
```

The values in curlybraces, {make} and {model}, are named tokens inside the string.  When you use format() on the string called html, you replace those tokens.  In this case, I referenced them directly by name.